# How to protect source code of firefox browser extension

Tags: javascript, firefox, google-chrome-extension, firefox-addon, browser-security

We are developing firefox browser extension. We are able to successfully install XPI and access the features that we have developed.

Major of the logic are written in JavaScript and HTML files. So anybody can unzip the XPI file and can see the source code. How to prevent this ? Is mozilla providing any encryption mechanism ?

The same features will be developed for other browsers like Chrome.

Comment: you can make it harder, but not impossible to rip off your code.

Comment: Its totally open source. You can't hide it. By making it harder its called obfuscation, but people that want your code know how to get around obfuscation.

Comment: Understood. If my JavaScript or HTML got obfuscated, will the XPI  still work? If so, it will be useful if you provide me the direction

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can obfuscate your JavaScript and your XPI will still work. JavaScript obfuscation keeps the functionality of your code but makes it harder to read and reuse (not impossible, though).

I'll leave you here the two tools that I've already tried:

Free: [uglifyjs](https://github.com/mishoo/UglifyJS) (only minification ie. removes unnecessary characters to make it smaller);

Not-free: [jscrambler](https://jscrambler.com) (seems to be the best pick if you are looking for obfuscation);

Google: [javascript | html5] [~protect | ~obfuscate] to find more obfuscation tools.

Answer (score 0):

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NPAPI

All good things get banned or abused, but they keep coming back in a different way !

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32448022)